# Http client : One or more validation errors occurred error

Tags: php, symfony, httpclient

I have an error when I execute an http request to retrieve data with the POST method in my symfony project

Code :

```
class ServiceAPI
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function getData(): array
    {
        $response = $this->client->request(
            'POST',
            'http://mydomaine.net/Article/GetArticles',
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                ],         
            ]
        );

        return $response->toArray();
    }
}
```

Image error :
[One or more validation errors occurred.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1uUg.png)

Comment: You have a validation on your route, and it's missing data. Check the validation rules for `Article/GetArticles` to see what you need to be passing in for a POST response. If you're just trying to get the list of articles, then it should probably be a GET response instead of a POST response.

Comment: @aynber, At the level of the API url, the designer used the POST method to retrieve the data, And to consume the API on my application I have an error
Noted that when I perform a test on Postman it works